# syntax to query another table using relationship in ORM?

Tags: database, orm, sqlalchemy

The model is like this(in SQLAlchemy):

```
Class Cell(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cell"
    id = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String)

Class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ =  "cell"
    id = Column(Integer)
    factor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("cell.id"))
    cell = relationship(Cell, backref = 'sample', order_by = "Cell.id")
```

When I execute the query like this:

```
DBSession.query(Sample).filter(Sample.cell.name == "a_string")
```

It throws an exception like this:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 139, in __getattr__
key)
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute  'name'
```

It seems that the `cell` field in `Sample` class doesn't have a field called `name`. Then how can I query `Cell.name` in `Sample` class with `cell` field? Does anyone have ideas about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve that:

#### 1. use join(...) - I would opt for this one in your case

```
qry = session.query(Sample).join(Cell).filter(Cell.name == "a_string")

>> SELECT sample.id AS sample_id, sample.factor_id AS sample_factor_id
>> FROM sample JOIN cell ON cell.id = sample.factor_id
>> WHERE cell.name = :name_1
```

#### 2. use any/has(...) - this will use a sub-query

```
qry = session.query(Sample).filter(Sample.cell.has(Cell.name == "a_string"))

>> SELECT sample.id AS sample_id, sample.factor_id AS sample_factor_id
>> FROM sample
>> WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
>> FROM cell
>> WHERE cell.id = sample.factor_id AND cell.name = :name_1)
```